# Only sections of line (LineString) rasterized in QGIS

Tags: qgis, rasterization

[image: Rasterizing result]

I would like to rasterize the above intersected line string.  Each colored section of the lines represent a different attribute value.  I would like to rasterize each section of the line; however, the rasterize (vector to raster) tool only rasterizes small sections of the lines.

There must be a topological problem or something causing it to not rasterize all sections of the line.  I've tried all the tools and used the fixed shapefile outputs, but they produce the same result.  I'm possibly using the tools incorrectly.

How do I fix this problem?

*** Answer to this question was to use the v.to.rast GRASS tool, but a similar result occurs when I apply the v.to.rast tool in the graphical modeler.

[image]

The above image shows the rasterized/transformed line vector from the graphical modeler, purple.  The manually derived line vector to raster is in black.  Why is the manually derived vector to raster result complete and the graphical modeler one incomplete?

Comment: I have found the GRASS v.to.rast tool works well for this application, rather than the GDAL QGIS rasterize tool.  Although the problem is solved for this application, I get a similar result when I apply v.to.rast to another file.

Answer (score 0):

everything fixed.  I changed the symbology properties to single band gray and it all shows up now.